# Is there a gap between a nonlinear program and a linear one?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Let us say that I have a nonlinear integer program $(P1)$ that is transformed to an integer linear one $(P2)$. Is there a gap between $(P1)$ and $(P2)$? At first, I thought that the gap should be zero (both $(P1)$ and $(P2)$ are equivalent) but I doubt that maybe it is not always zero. Is there any reference that can help me to answer this question?

Comment: If P1 and P2 really are equivalent then by definition there is no gap.

Comment: You need to clearly tell us what the transformation is. I suggest you also show us this transformation on a specific problem.  Then people will have a question to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linear programming problems the optimal value of a target function is at the corners while for the non-linear programing  the optimal value could occur at any point.

To better understand the difference, consider a piece of paper and cut it into a polygon.

If you keep this paper in various positions and observe the highest and the lowest point, you see that they happen at some corner or the other .

That is not  necessarily the case if you fold the paper or cut  it arbitrarily or deform it so it looses it flatness.